# How C function returns value which size more than a word in ARM architecture

Tags: c++, c, arm

In C program, memory layout consist of .BSS, .DATA, .TEXT, HEAP and STACK. when a function returns value which size less than a word, it goes to R0 register, but if the return value is large than a word, it returns by memory. for example:

```
LargeType t;
t = func(arg);
```

is implemented as:

```
LargeType t;
(void) func(&t,arg);
```

my question is which part of the memory the compiler use to past "t"?

Comment: _"when a function returns value which size less than a word, it goes to R1 register"_ You mean `r0`?

Comment: Havn't you essentially answered your own question, in that it's implemented as `func(&t,arg);` - in which case the caller managed the memory and just pass in a pointer to that memory - i.e. it's just as any other argument to the function. Exactly where `t` itself is allocated is a bit more complicated if it's C++ instead of C though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ARM C++ ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0041d/index.html) essentially uses the Itanium C++ ABI except for exceptions. In that ABI the calling convention for returning a large object by value is that the caller passes a hidden pointer and the function uses that pointer to create the object in the return statement. This is how Return Value Optimization is implemented.

Now, the translation that you present is incorrect. The code that you start with uses assignment not initialization:

```
LargeType t;
t = func(arg);
```

The translation done by the compiler will be equivalent to:

```
LargeType t;
LargeType __tmp;
func(&__tmp,arg);
t.operator=(__tmp);
__tmp.~LargeType();
```

The temporary variable will be created in the stack, the address passed to the function that will use it to create the object. Then assignment will happen and at the end of the complete expression `t = func(arg);` the temporary will be destroyed.

Compare that with the initialization case:

```
LargeType t = func(arg);
```

In this case the compiler can do the transformation you mention, and the translated code would be:

```
LargeType t;
func(&t,arg);
```

The very important difference is that initialization and assignment are completely different operations. In the case of initialization the object *becomes*, there was nothing, now there is something. In the case of assignment the object already *was*, it has a state, and it might be managing resources. If the transformation you suggested was allowed this code would leak memory:

```
struct Test {
   int *p;  // assume other members make this object large
   Test() : p(new int()) {}
   Test(int i) : p(new int) { *p = i; }
   Test(Test const & other) : p(new int) { *p = other->p; }
   ~Test() { delete p; }
   Test& operator=(Test const & other) { *p = other->p; }
};
Test f(int arg) {
    return Test(1)
}
Test t;
t = f(5);
```

Where the transformed code would leak:

```
Test t;    // allocates a pointer
f(&t, 5);  // expands to:
           // __ret->p = new int;  // leak!
           // *(__ret->p) = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling func(&t, arg) will go ahead and populate the memory address of t with the required value. So t will have to allocated on the stack of the caller function (unless you want to do a dynamic allocation of t, as t = malloc(sizeof(LargeType)), in which it will be on the heap). Not sure what the compiler has got to do here.

```
/* Caller function */
...
LargeType t;     /* Allocated on caller's stack */
LargeType *t = malloc(sizeof(LargeType));    /* Allocation on heap */
(void) func(&t, arg);    /* Fills up t with required value */
```